# TypeScript serverless-esbuild exclude "*" (full node_modules) doesn't seem to work

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, esbuild

I use serverless-layers plugin in Serverless Framework so I'd like to exclude node_modules directory from esbuild.

According to [the official document](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-esbuild), I can set "*" to the exclude option of serverless-esbuild to exclude the full node_modules directory.

> An array of dependencies to exclude from the Lambda. This is passed to the esbuild external option. Set to * to disable packaging node_modules    ['aws-sdk']

However, it doesn't seem to work if I set it in `serverless.ts`.
Here was my trials:

```
exclude: ['*']
```

```
exclude: '*'
```

```
exclude: ['./node_modules/*']
```

On the other hand, specifying each library works well like this:

```
exclude: ['aws-sdk', 'mysql2', '@middy']
```

Is there something I missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

esbuild automatically includes node_modules. If you don't want that to be included, you can add esbuild-node-externals plugin.

```js
const { nodeExternalsPlugin } = require("esbuild-node-externals");

esbuild
    .build({
      entryPoints: [entryFile],
      outfile: outFile,
      minify: true,
      bundle: true,
      target: TARGET,
      plugins: [copyPlugin, nodeExternalsPlugin()],
      sourcemap: true,
      platform: "node",
      define,
      external: ["pg", "sqlite3", "tedious", "pg-hstore"],
    })
    .then((r) => {
      console.log(`Build ${entryFile} to ${outFile} succeeded.`);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log("Error building:", e.message);
      process.exit(1);
    });
```